# Print text when key pressed

Tags: java, input

Can anyone please help me with this?

```
public class DemoTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    keyPressed();
}

public static void keyPressed() {
    //If player presses the key 1 then print the line:
    System.out.println("You pressed the key 1");
}

}
```

Now I want something to be printed out when you press the 1 key.

Comment: Look into `System.in`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class DemoTest {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        keyPressed();
    }

    public static void keyPressed() {
        //If player presses the key 1 then print the line:
        int x;
        try {
            x = input.nextInt();
            if (x==1)
                System.out.println("You pressed the key 1");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You haven't entered a number!!!");
        }

    }

}
```

The try-catch block is only for making sure that the player will input a number.

Answer (score -1):

try these lines of code:

```
 public class DemoTest implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1 ) {
       .....
       }

    }
```

Comment: This answer presumes a program using a Swing GUI, while the question is clearly a basic "hello-world" level program that does not use Swing.